# Tracking a custom entity from Outlook using Outlook plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM, and I have run into requirement where a user should have an option to convert any email to a custom entity request. When I installed CRM-Outlook plugin in my outlook (I am using Office 2010) then I see option to Track an email and then convert to either opportunity, lead and case.

How can I add my custum entity to the list so that email can be associated with the request?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Ashfaq.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add your custom entity to the OOTB list as CRM doesn't "know" how to convert an email into an instance of your custom entity. Only option I can think of is to add custom email ribbon functionality. Lots of info elsewhere in Stack Overflow on this.